# how to create default auto increment name in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I'm doing a project in iPhone where i'm using sqlite database. I have a text view where user can enter any text to create a note, and a text field where user can enter the name of that note. In database I've created two column 1st is note and 2nd is noteName, where noteName is the primary key. Now i want, if any user forget to enter the name of the note, then it will create a default name such as untitled name with a index which will increment automatically after every note creation.
Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly -- count the number of rows present in your table by a simple SELECT query.

And Append that "Count+1" number to noteName and insert that row in your database.